# Swap items in LinkedList so lesser value is first

Tags: java, linked-list

sortPairs is a function that is supposed to swap two consecutive ListNodes in a LinkedList to ensure that the one of lesser value comes first in the list. My code errors for some tests because it does not reach the final two nodes. For instance, I had a test case where [10, 20, 60, 50, 40, 30] was transformed to [10] -> [20] -> [50] -> [60] -> [40] -> [30], but it should have been [10] -> [20] -> [50] -> [60] -> [30] -> [40]

```
public void sortPairs(){


    if(front==null || front.next ==null)
        return;

    ListNode current= front;

    while(current.next!=null && current.next.next!=null){

        if(current.data<=current.next.data){
            current=current.next.next;
        }

        else{
           int temp= current.data;

            current.data=current.next.data;
            current.next.data=temp;

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: When you say `current = current.next.next`, you're skipping over `current.next`

Comment: Note that `front` is typically called `head`.

Comment: Also, in your else branch, the value of `current` is not updated

Comment: @user how would I update current?

Comment: `current = current.next`

Comment: @user that did not change anything

Comment: Could you append your updated code to your post?

Comment: @user public void sortPairs(){
    
    
    if(front==null || front.next ==null)
        return;
    
    ListNode current= front;
    
    while(current.next!=null && current.next.next!=null){
        
        if(current.data<=current.next.data){
            current=current.next.next;
        }
        
        else{
            
           int temp= current.data;
            
            current.data=current.next.data;
            current.next.data=temp;
            //added part
            current=current.next;
       
        }
       
    }
    
    
}

Comment: You should also change `current=current.next.next` in your if-statement to `current=current.next`, as I mentioned before